# R: match elements in n position of two vectors

Tags: r, vector, match

I have a loop that generates different values and sizes of two vectors at each run. Nevertheless, the new vectors always match in size.

In this loop I have some equation that always indicates a value in the new vector A. I need to take the value in vector B that corresponds to the same position my result is in the vector A.

Here is some exemple without the loop code..

```
vecA <- c(3, 4, 5, 10, 32)
vecB <- c(0, 1, 2,  0,  1) 
res_vecA <- x + y
matching <- res %in% vec2 # not quite right, I Know.
```

If the result of the equation in `res_vecA` were to be 10 ( i.e `vecA[4]`), how do I get the value in the corresponding position in the vector B (i.e vecB[4])?

Comment: not bad description but much better would be *reproducible input* and clear expected output.

Comment: `vecB[match(10, vecA)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the which() function 
`vecB[which(vecA == res_vecA)]`

Comment: Almost there. But your solution gives me correspondence of values. Since 10 in not in the vector B, it returs FALSE. But that is not what i need. Say for one loop run the pointed value in vector A is 10. I need the to take 0 in the vector B just because 0 is in the same position as 10 while comparing the vectors.

Comment: As per your example, value of res_vecA = 10;
the `which(vecA == res_vecA)` will check at which position is that value present (in this case 4)
finally, vecB[4] will return 0
Is this not what you want?

Comment: your are completely right. When I apply to my real data set I change the ordering of the objects in you solution. It works just fine. Thank you.